# Is it possible to get a Ph.D. position in Europe after a one-year diploma?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, career-path, europe, australia

I had interviewed by a professor for a Ph.D. position in Australia and the application has been unsuccessful. However, the professor wrote I did well in the interview and encouraged me to apply for a one-year diploma or two years master's (As I only have a 4 years bachelor's degree). I want to know what is the main difference? I mean if I do a diploma, will I be eligible for doing a Ph.D. after that? Especially in Europe (as Europe needs a master's for getting a Ph.D.)?

Comment: Could you explain what the difference is between masters and diploma aside from the length?

Comment: Also, do you have a specific country/uni/prof in mind?

Comment: Master's degrees in Spain are sometimes one year long (or used to be a few years ago), after which you can apply to a PhD program. In any case, each PhD program might have slightly different requirements or provisions for exceptions, so it's probably best to contact the particular programs you're interested in directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are eligible for a PhD in some European countries with just a bachelor's degree. There may exist countries <s>- e.g., I believe Germany -</s>* where a master's degree is universally required before a PhD. In other countries, requirements vary between institutes (and supervisors may even insist upon their own requirements). So a list of countries probably isn't useful and exceptions would no doubt exist.

<sup>* A comment clarifies that a master's degree is not a universal requirement in Germany. Another comments notes, "it might not be possible to employ the PhD student as a scientific employee (Wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter), which is the default for PhD students in many fields," so, for practical purposes I presume a master's is a widespread norm in Germany.</sup>

Comment: Which countries?

Comment: Numerous, for example, see https://www.studyineurope.eu/, noting that a country's institutes may have different requirements. I believe institutes in Germany require a master's degree for PhDs, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @mmeent The URL provides the answers you are looking for. If you can't be bothered to look, then take France as an example.

Comment: Also, from that website: *"In the event you are applying for doctoral studies at university in France, you are required to be in possession of a relevant master's degree diploma."*

Comment: @mmeent The website is wrong in that instance. In France it is possible (although uncommon) to complete a PhD without a master's.

Comment: @mmeent Entertain me: About what?

Comment: Can you give the precise list? And could you give an example where it is not uncommon (like in France) ?

Comment: In Germany some Länder allow for the possibility of a PhD after a Bachelor. But Germany would even allow universities to grant somebody a professorship without a phd, without a bachelor's degree - provided the somebody is a genius.

Comment: A master's degree is a common, but not universal requirement in Germany for a PhD.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thanks for the clarification, I'll edit.

Comment: @user111388 I have no intention of checking every country in Europe.

Comment: In Germany, even though one might be allowed to do a PhD with just a bachelor's, the practical conditions might be undesirable. Specifically, it might not be possible to employ the PhD student as a scientific employee (Wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter), which is the default for PhD students in many fields.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper: I don't see how one could argue that someone qualified to pursue PhD studies would at the same time not be qualified to be wiss. MA. (But I'm very much aware that a given administration may mean that something that should be possible becomes impossible in a particular place at a particular time.) The procedure I'm familiar with is to require foreign students whose thesis is not automatically considered equivalent to a German Master thesis  to pass some exams that show they perform at the required level in the field of their PhD studies.